# Xamarin - XAML - top bar app menu

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am working on Xamarin Mac app with XAML, but I am not able to add app menu to top bar. I think, that it is generated with xCode in Main.storyboard, but I am not using xCode, because of using XAML.

Comment: This documentation looks pretty useful, if you have read it? [Menus in Xamarin.Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/mac/user-interface/menu). If you scroll about half way down there is a step-by-step guide into making a menu bar . Hopefully this is of use :)

Comment: @Alfie - it is usefull, but only when you use layout / frontend via xcode, but I am using xaml frontend. I found solution for creating status menu, but can not find how to create app menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. I post it here for someone who can use it.

For adding menu item for quit app (in AppDelegate.cs):

```
// top bar app menu
NSMenu menubar = new NSMenu();
NSMenuItem appMenuItem = new NSMenuItem();
menubar.AddItem(appMenuItem);

NSMenu appMenu = new NSMenu();

// add quit menu item
string quitTitle = String.Format("Quit {0}", "appname");
var quitMenuItem = new NSMenuItem(quitTitle, "q", delegate {
    NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(menubar);
});
appMenu.AddItem(quitMenuItem);

// finally add menu
NSApplication.SharedApplication.MainMenu = menubar;
```

Comment: is it possible to see the entire file AppDelegate.cs content ?
Note: it seems the object appMenu is never used. Is it correct?